# Typescript - How can I extend an interface with an existing property?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building a UI system via React using Typescript. I want to create an `<Input />` component that composes a real `<input />`. The component `<Input />` should accept as a prop every attribute that is accepted by the `<input />`.

In order to do so, I checked what `<input />` in React accepts, and that was the result:

```
React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>;
```

At first, I set my interface like so:

```
interface InputProps extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>;
```

but it's too long to be understandable. So I thought about using `Pick`:

```
interface InputProps extends Pick<JSX.IntrinsicElements, 'input'>`
```

but it just adds to the interface the `input` property itself, instead of actually extend it:

```
interface Props extends ...  {}

const Input = (props: Props) => {
    return <input {...props} />
}
```

Answer (score 6):

interface for native input is `HTMLInputElement`

```
interface InputProps extends HTMLInputElement {}
```

interface with React props

```
import { InputHTMLAttributes } from "react";

interface InputProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
```

to access the ref use Forwarding Ref:

```
const MyInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return(<input {...props} ref={ref} />);
});
```

Comment: And what about React's additional props such as `ref`?